# SQL Query Optimizer - how does cost vary with resource availability

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

When the query optimizer calculates the cost of an execution plan, can you expect the plan to differ depending on the amount of resource available to it?

Take the following scenario:

- You have a VMware virtual machine running SQL Server 2008 R2 with 32GB RAM, 8 CPU cores hooked up to a SAN. There are 7 VMs sharing the host box.
- You find CPU usage is peaking at 130% regularly, so you move most of the VMs off the host, leaving only 3 of the original 7 VMs including the SQL Server box.
- You immediately find that actual performance is *slower* now that more CPU headroom is available to it. You can see that CPU utilization on the guest is going much higher (because more CPU resource is available for use) than the 30% it could muster before. Despite this, users of the application see a marked slowdown in performance.

My interpretation of why a SQL VM performs slower when more CPU resource is available to it is that the procedure cache contains plans calculated under/optimized for an environment with less CPU availability. When the extra resource becomes available, the procedure cache will provide sub-optimal plans which may perform less well.

Does this make sense? We had this exact scenario a couple of weeks back and had lots of complaints about performance as soon as we stopped the CPU thrashing on the host. I ran dbcc freeprocache and thereafter performance seemed to improve - either that or the users got used to it.

Thoughts?
Thanks

Comment: Possibly you have bloated proc cache - have you set optimize for adhoc ON? freeing up proccache is just duct taping the problem without getting to the root.

Comment: Thanks for your input Kin, but maybe you can explain what you mean? Optimize for adhoc is OFF. How would you suggest that simply adding more CPU resource would slow things down here? Don't worry about my freeprocache - I'd like your thoughts on the problem, not the workaround. Does that make sense?

Comment: Kimberly has an excellent post on [Plan cache and optimizing for adhoc workloads](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/plan-cache-and-optimizing-for-adhoc-workloads/). Also, try running sp_whoisactive when you see CPU is pegging high.

Comment: Yes that's a great post thanks for passing it on. I'm quite sure I can benefit from enabling adhoc optimization. To rephrase my question: Does the query optimizer produce a different plan if a more powerful CPU is available (not more cores, just more MHz to go around)?

Comment: I believe the pure speed of the CPU wouldn't cause it to change the query plan - it should be doing the most efficient one it can no matter the CPU speed resource available. It should always do the one it believes is the most efficient due to the optimizer working per process, it can't see others and doesn't know how much resource they require, therefore should always select the most efficient. But the number of cores I think does affect the query plan due to paralleling possibilities - table scans may be more efficient if they can be paralleled with a fast IO and multiple slow cores.

Comment: My point here is that when you removed the VMs you may have inadvertently changed the processors available to the remaining VMs in a way that resulted in less or MORE possibilities for parallelism, either which may slow down your queries, depending on what is happening and the set up of your system. Prior to moving the VMs you hopefully ran a few traces recording ShowPlan event classes. Run another trace on the systems again once the VMs are removed and compare query plans used. Hopefully they should point you to an answer about what the optimizer is doing.

Comment: This is good thinking, thanks for your help. Unfortunately we have server-wide MAXDOP = 1 so, absolutely no risk of parallelism :) With parallelism not being an issue, and the procedure cache being pretty much the same before and after the change, I'm still currently having trouble explaining this behavior.

Comment: This may be a hardware thing: I saw something on a Dell server that behaved in a similar way: the default settings (BIOS) is some kind of 'max performance/energy consumption'. This causes the processors to enter a sleep state quite often - particularly under database load. I saw 50% degradation of speed. If you had other load on the machine, it may have caused the server not to get asleep and thus get higher performance. Look into the bios and try to set it to 'max performance' or something similar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**First, some background information**

So far (until SQL Server 2014) the query optimiser will only take a few things into account:

- The number of CPU cores available on the system
- The current amount of memory in use

**CPU cores:** The core count assigned to SQL Server from the affinity mask determines how efficient it can possibly be to create a parallel plan. For example, on a system with 4 cores, you can expect a 4x speedup when switching to a parallel plan, whereas a system with 2 cores only get a doubling. Because of this, the core count can affect the choice of plan. Unfortunately, not every query can scale linearly with the core count, yet the optimiser will believe it does. This means that on machines with more than around 12-16 cores, getting more parallelism will actually SLOW the query down. The speed of the CPU is not taken into account, only the number of cores.

**Memory Available**: When the plan is made, the amount of memory available is taken into account. This determines strategies like hash joins, sort space and other memory intensive operations. Mis-estimation here is very dangerous and can lead to poor performance. Especially if you over estimate the memory available for a hash join and have to spill into `tempdb`.

**Your specific case**

Without measurements of your system it is difficult, if not impossible, to know exactly what happened in your scenario. There are too many variables that potentially changed at the same time. It may simply be that something else has changed in the environment. Any diagnosis is pure guesswork and real DBA work is a science, not an arty exercise in guessing.

You would need to collect the following to get knowledge.

- The query plans before/after
- Wait stats
- Exact machine configuration (both for the host and the VM in the virtualised scenario)

Comment: Thanks for explaining that, much appreciated. I have the query plans before and after, the wait stats and the exact machine config. I agree guesswork is not useful.

Comment: Please attach the plans, wait stats and config. This would allow us to shed more light on it.